# React Native - Debugger Worker error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` when use `Debug JS Remotely`. This error is from `debuggerWorker.js` `<!doctype html><div><a href="/debug/bundles">Cached Bundles</a></div>`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the very same issue after upgrading to 0.50.3 of react native.  I fought for a day, but than the problem suddenly disappeared.  Did multiply things, but it probably was reloading the chrome tab/restarting chrome ;-)

Comment: Can confirm had the same problem with 0.50.3, restarted chrome and the problem resolved itself

Comment: A simple refresh cache did the job for me

Comment: wow so simple yet I've never thought about it. thanks a lot :D